# Make compatible a android application to ios also

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I have developed a project on android but now I want to make it compatible for ios also. How a project could run on two operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing some research on cross-platform development such as https://xamarin.com/.

You should be able to use the general logic behind your android app to develop the code using xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOs are totally different platforms so basically you cant just run an Android app on iOs. But you can try using cross-platform tools like Xamarin to publish your app in several different platforms. For example in Xamarin you write your app with C# and publish it on iOs and Android at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are different flavors you can use to develop on both platforms. It all depends on your skills and preferences, or whether you want to learn something new. The most popular languages are the following:

**Xamarin** - Used mostly as a plugin with Visual Studio, and based on the C# programming language.

**Cordova** - An Apache language which lets you develop for both platforms.

**Phonegap** - the Adobe flavor of Cordova.

**Sencha** - If you are more into JavaScript, you can use this flavor to develop apps for both IOS and Android.

Kindly note that all of the above are subject to subscription and payment, although flavors like Sencha come with a free version too.

Hope this helps.